# Curious Chrome browser extension ("BeestSaveFoorYou")

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I run the Chrome browser on my Windows 7 PC. Recently, an extension has appeared called "BeestSaveFoorYou." A Google search returns no information about what this might be. I have attempted to delete it, apparently successfully, but it keeps coming back. When I merely disable it, it remains disabled (or at least it says so).

Does anyone have any idea what this is and what it does? I suspect it is malware of some sort, but none of my security utilities take any notice of it.

Answer (score 0):

It almost certainly is malware; it it served a purpose it wouldn't have a peculiar name like that. Best remove or at least the very least disable it:

from Chrome browser goto:

```
chrome://extensions/
```

and click on trash can. Alternatively you can disable it though I would recommend immediate removal. Beware though as malware is often designed to "stick" to your PC using registry settings and other persistent mechanisms. Removal of the extension is no guarantee it has actually been eradicated from your PC.

Comment: Since posting this, I have removed the "BeestSaveFoorYou" extension twice, and it has returned twice. Using Regedit, I located and deleted the several registry keys that mentioned "BeestSaveFoorYou." This has no permanent effect. As of a few minutes ago, a Google search still provides no information. It gives me answers for, "Best Save For You," which are totally irrelevant. When I tell it that I really did mean to ask for "BeestSaveFoorYou," my original question and this answer are all that comes up -- although they do show up on four other websites.

Comment: The malware regenerates from binary code sitting somewhere on your computer. The only way is guarantee success in this case is to re-install the OS. Especially given that no-one on the net knows about this particular malware.